# Is Sputnik V the first registered vaccine against COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19, russia, vaccines

Sputnik V vaccine's [official website](https://sputnikvaccine.com/about-vaccine/) claims that their product is the first registered against the disease.

> Sputnik V is the world’s first registered vaccine based on a well-studied human adenoviral vector-based platform.

Comment: "What do they exactly mean by "registered"" <- This means this is off-topic. A skeptic question is supposed to be about empirical facts and not about word interpretation.

Comment: @Christian I'm surprised to see that you just focused on a little drop of water in an ocean. However, my question isn't about that! It's just a secondary thing.

Comment: I think Christian's question/critique is very valid. This isn't really framed as a very good skeptical questions.

Comment: @LarianLeQuella If the problem is just that sentence, I will remove it.

Comment: @aminabzz It's the job of a question to be clear what it means with it's terms.

Comment: It's still unclear what "registered" means. It's not that the sentence was unclear, but rather you need to define what "registered" means. Registered with whom? Under what sort of criteria is something considered registered. What makes it worldwide? etc. I can say I am the first person in the world registered in something I just made up (the first registered Professional Pedantic Organizational Program Manager for Science and Skepticism). While technically true, it's meaningless.

Comment: @Christian The job of a question is to question the validity of a notable claim.  I see two patterns on Skeptics when the claim itself is ambiguous: the asker provides some narrower interpretation of the claim that they are asking about OR the answerer clarifies the interpretation of the claim that they are responding to.  I do not see anything in the Skeptics rules or FAQ indicating that the asker is required to provide the clarification.

Comment: @Eric: It was approved (registered) by the  Russian  analog of American CDC. Recall that there are about 150 million people living in Russia.

Comment: @LarianLeQuella Why should I (the asker) define what "registered" means here? It was the Sputnik website's duty to clarify it, not mine. I am just asking about their claim. and also, the meaning of "registered" is my question too. If I knew what they meant by "registered", I wouldn't ask about it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is indeed [the first registered vaccine](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2021/02/10/russia-sputnik-vaccine-underestimated/). But the registration process in Russia is different than in other countries (say, USA). They basically skipped the third stage: testing the vaccine on a large number of humans. So the vaccination which is happening in Russia can be viewed as the third phase of testing. Thus even though it was registered first, it could not be viewed as thoroughly tested, at least till a few days ago.